# PHP Lighthouse Laravel - Get resources via the authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Is there a way to get resources (example: Posts) via the authenticated user? Like this:

```
Auth::user()->posts()
```

Schema:

```
type Query @guard(with: ["api"]) {
    me_posts: [Post!]! @auth
}
```

Comment: Should be `Auth::user()->posts` or if there is a chance user is not authenticated then better to use with check: `optional(Auth::user())->posts` since property gives you a collection while method gives you a query builder. Pay attention on `->posts` vs. `->posts()`.

Comment: You can also use a scope, so you won't need a custom field resolver.

Comment: I would rather use `{ me { posts {...} } }`. And in Scheme: `{me: User @auth}`, and `type User { posts: [Post!]! @hasMany }`

Comment: you can custom resolver and `return Auth::user()->posts()`. you can try the `@whereAuth` using the relation too.